# What happens if we just use "signed" and "unsigned" without any primitive data types?

Tags: c++

What happens if we do not put an int or char after unsigned and signed variables?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned u = 10; // how is this declaration helpful?
    signed s = 12;   // is there any use with such declarations without specifying a primitive datatype 
    cout << u << "  " << s << endl;  // prints the values of the variables as usual
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`signed` and `unsigned` implicitly mean `signed int` and `unsiged int`, respectively.